# How to delete user accounts in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, forms-authentication

I have a Register page, I used the following [Walkthrough: Creating a Web Site with Membership and User Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx) to make my webpage. The problem is the Registration page creates users, but I am clueless about how to delete user accounts from the Database where it gets stored.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The membership provider has a DeleteUser method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6b0zxdw.aspx

The following works just as well:

`Membership.DeleteUser("username");`

---

If you want a SQL based solution:

http://web.archive.org/web/20130407080036/http://blogs.rawsoft.nl/remco/post/2009/02/05/How-to-Remove-users-from-the-ASPNet-membership-database.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to Create users in a Disabled state until admin allows the user permission to use account?

Comment: Membership.CreateUser() Method has a parameter called IsApproved. You can use it.

Comment: @Chris Lively The SQL-Based solution link seems to be down: http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/blogs.rawsoft.nl.html

Comment: I have been successful at deleting with SQL using this link: http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/bulk-delete-asp-net-membership-users/

Comment: If I have a running application (in my case deployed on azure), where Do I write `Membership.DeleteUser("username");`? In a migration script? Or do I add a Action only I as Admin can reach and in there I execute that command?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simpler way to delete a user using SQL.

```
USE ASPNet
GO

DECLARE @UserId uniqueidentifier
SET @UserId = 'THE GUID OF THE USER HERE'

DELETE FROM aspnet_Profile WHERE UserID = @UserId
DELETE FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles WHERE UserID = @UserId
DELETE FROM aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser WHERE UserID = @UserId
DELETE FROM dbo.aspnet_Membership WHERE UserID = @UserId
DELETE FROM aspnet_users WHERE UserID = @UserId
```

Answer (score 7):

For the completeness' sake, here is a solution similar to Yasser's, however, with using the **UserName** instead of the GUID as the OP has asked:

```
DECLARE @UserId uniqueidentifier
SET @UserId = (SELECT TOP(1) UserID FROM aspnet_Users 
  WHERE UserName = 'THE USERNAME OF THE USER HERE')

DELETE FROM aspnet_Profile WHERE UserID = @UserId
DELETE FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles WHERE UserID = @UserId
DELETE FROM aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser WHERE UserID = @UserId
DELETE FROM dbo.aspnet_Membership WHERE UserID = @UserId
DELETE FROM aspnet_users WHERE UserID = @UserId
```

Note: Base SQL script taken from [this blog by Tim Gaunt](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2008/01/13/How+To+Remove+Users+From+The+ASPNet+Membership+Database.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

On your project (Visual Studio) Top menu > Website > ASP.NET Configurations (Click on this)

It will open the configurations and then Security > Manage Users 
Do what you need there...

Comment: He probably wants to do this in his own website

Comment: I would like to do it both ways, i do not see `Manage Users`, i see `manage access rules`

Comment: Under Security Tab you get three boxes (Users, Roles, Access Rules). Manage Users is in the Users box. I am looking at VS2010 your may be different but it is there. Have a look label may be different...

Answer (score 1):

When creating a WebSite that is going to have a Membership manage users and roles, create an Admin/Support Web Page within your site that will be only visible available for Roles that can perform such operations as:

- Delete User
- Reset Password
- Other Users management

It will come in handy when you have to support your End Users and the problems they are going to face.

[Membership info from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz.aspx)

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly what you said about. The problem is I still can't figure out how to delete a member. I'm using a gridview to display all the members and using the delete feature that was automatically added. I would like to use a stored procedure or a method behind the code, but the only examples I can find are the Membership.DeleteUser("username"); which I can't get to work for me. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps :

- open the folder location `C:program file / microsoft visual studio 12/`
- search for developer `Command prompt` .
- write the command : devenv /resetuserdata

  [image]